# Sort python dictionary by date key

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

In the main dictionary, the date was a value. There were data with same date. So then I took the date and grouped it by creating a 2 dimensional dict where date is the key.

```
data = {
    "01-01-2015" : "some data",
    "05-05-2015" : "some data",
    "03-04-2015" : "some data"
}
```

Now I want to sort it by the date descending so that it will look like this:

```
data = {
    "05-05-2015" : "some data",
    "03-04-2015" : "some data",
    "01-01-2015" : "some data"
}
```

How can I achieve that?
**I am using python 2.6**

Comment: why is `"03-04-2015"`  before `"05-05-2015"`?

Comment: *By date key?* The second code block is your expect or the first one is? And by the way, you need [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: A simple google/stackoverflow search will tell you clearly that **a python dictionary can't be sorted.**
A different structure will have to be used. (ex- OrderedDict). Try it and let us know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort a dictionary by key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key)

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 16):

<s>The idea here is to use `OrderedDict` as `dictionary` has no scope for ordering while OrderedDict preserves the entry order.</s>

The idea here is to use `list of tuples of (key, value) pairs` as `dictionary` has no scope for ordering while OrderedDict preserves the entry order.
Also we must **convert the keys to actual `datetime` object** for the sort to work perfectly otherwise sorting on string based fields happen alphabetically.

**Code :**

```
from datetime import datetime
#from collections import OrderedDict


data = {
    "01-01-2015" : "some data",
    "05-05-2015" : "some data",
    "03-04-2015" : "some data"
}

#ordered_data = OrderedDict(
#    sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[0], '%d-%m-%Y'), reverse=True))

#Since OP is using python 2.6 where OrderedDict is not present, I changed the solution and the original solution is commented out
ordered_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[0], '%d-%m-%Y'), reverse=True)

print(ordered_data)
```

**Output :**

```
[('05-05-2015', 'some data'), ('03-04-2015', 'some data'), 
('01-01-2015', 'some data')]
```

**Explanation :** (For converting keys to datetime for sorting)

If you keep the date field as string then the lexicographical order is considered and `3` comes after `0` hence `a>b` is `True` but same is not true for their date counterparts. `Feb` definitely comes after `Jan`.

```
a = "30-01-2015"
b = "01-02-2015"

print(a>b)    #True

a_datetime = datetime.strptime(a, '%d-%m-%Y')
b_datetime = datetime.strptime(b, '%d-%m-%Y')

print(a_datetime>b_datetime) #False
```

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention the python version. It's 2.6 that I am using and OrderedDict is from 2.7+

Comment: Just use 
`ordered_data = sorted(data.items(), key = lambda x:datetime.strptime(x[0], '%d-%m-%Y'), reverse=True)`.
Only thing is you will not be able to use dictionary's `key` advantage as you will get a list of tuple as output.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the sorted method of python that will automatically sort your data on date and return a list.

```
data = {"01-01-2015" : "some data","05-05-2015" : "some data","03-04-2015" : "some data"}
sorted(data.items(), reverse=True)
```

that will produce the result:

```
[('05-05-2015', 'some data'), ('03-04-2015', 'some data'), ('01-01-2015', 'some data')]
```